# How do I completely remove the Global menu on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity, 13.10, globalmenu

I want to know how can I remove the Global menu bar completely.  The old tweaks for 12.04 isn't work completely for all apps like the Terminal and Nautilus.

Comment: Why do I get -1 for this question?

Comment: How can you successfully accomplish any task without global menu (that is mean without indicator panel)? =)

Comment: Quite easily, just add a menu to each program with a simple command I have used.  It was easy to do up until now.  I find the Global Menu slows me down.  If my Terminal has a menu my task is completed quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, it is so much easier working with many windows if they have the menu in their window.

I found this command to work.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '@a{sv} {"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu": <int32 0>}'
```

That I found on [Global menu in Ubuntu 13.10 - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173226)

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it didn't work for me.  I tend not to install tweaking software, but for some reason Unsettings took care of the issue for me.  I will never understand the Global Menu feature, or use it.

Answer (score -1):

First, install Synaptic package manager, search for global menu and uninstall what you find under 'installed'. Restart Unity and that is it.

Comment: When you say "search for the global menu" what is the actual name of the global menu?